# How to setup latest version of liquibase through bash script?

Tags: bash, github, liquibase, sourceforge

I used to install liquibase older version e.g

```
   `wget https://github.com/downloads/liquibase/liquibase/liquibase-2.0.5-bin.tar.gz`
```

and proceed with extraction and move it to desired location . I am unable to locate latest version of 
liquibase on github. Probably its removed or unavailable ?

[Liquibase download page](http://www.liquibase.org/download/index.html) has only link to source-forge , could someone help me how to `wget` a package from source-forge ?

**Edit**
 I am not sure of github, it seems there are no builds available for latest version. However, my complete script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless
sudo apt-get install -y libmysql-java
LV="3.1.1"
function setupLiquibase(){
  source $HOME/.profile

  INSTALLED="$(command -v liquibase)"

  # if not added already
  if [ -z "$LIQUIBASE_HOME" ]
    then
      echo  'export MYSQL_JCONNECTOR=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar'|sudo tee -a $HOME/.profile
      echo  'export LIQUIBASE_HOME=/usr/local/liquibase' |sudo tee -a $HOME/.profile
      echo  'export PATH=$PATH:$LIQUIBASE_HOME'|sudo tee -a $HOME/.profile
  fi

  if [ -z "$INSTALLED" ]
    then
        echo "Installing liquibase $LV "
        sudo rm -rf liquibase*
        wget http://kaz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/liquibase/Liquibase%20Core/liquibase-"$LV"-bin.tar.gz
        gunzip liquibase-"$LV"-bin.tar.gz
        sudo mkdir /usr/local/liquibase
        sudo tar -xf liquibase-"$LV"-bin.tar -C /usr/local/liquibase
        sudo chmod +x /usr/local/liquibase/liquibase
    else
        INSTALLED="$(liquibase --version)"
        echo "Liquibase is already installed, ${INSTALLED}"
  fi
}

setupLiquibase
```

Comment: See this older post, it should yeild your answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86971/how-do-i-download-from-sourceforge-with-wget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to download it with this command line

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/liquibase/files/Liquibase%20Core/liquibase-3.2.0-bin.tar.gz/download -O liquibase-3.2.0-bin.tar.gz
```

To choose a filename for the download you can specify the option `-O nomefile` (Note that it is a capital o not a 0).

If you forget (like I did the first time) to specify -O nomefile you will have on the hard disk a file with the name as guessed by wget. So:

```
http://Site/FullPath/liquibase-3.2.0-bin.tar.gz/download  --> download
```

and after you have to rename *by hands* the file `download`.

If instead it was

```
http://Site/FullPath/liquibase-3.2.0-bin.tar.gz  --> liquibase-3.2.0-bin.tar.gz
```

you will have directly the file with the correct name.

Answer (score 3):

Github moved downloads section to `/release`.

So your url becomes:

```
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/archive/liquibase-parent-3.2.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is only source package. I could not find the jar builds for the latest version

Answer (score 3):

I use [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to download liquibase and its database driver dependencies from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/).

Ivy itself is just a jar and can also be [downloaded](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.ivy%22%20AND%20a%3a%22ivy%22) from Maven Central.

## Example

This example runs a standard liquibase changeset and creates a [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database. The bash script will download and cache required jars.

```
├── changesets
│   └── scottTiger.xml
├── ivy.xml
├── liquibase.properties
└── liquibase.sh
```

Run as follows

```
./liquibase.sh update
```

### liquibase.sh

Apache ivy can be used as an [executable jar](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar $HOME/.ant/lib/ivy.jar \
     -error \
     -ivy ivy.xml \
     -main liquibase.integration.commandline.Main \
     -args $@
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.liquibase" name="liquibase-core" rev="latest.release" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="com.h2database" name="h2" rev="latest.release" conf="default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

### liquibase.properties

```
url=jdbc:h2:./db/scottTiger
driver=org.h2.Driver
username=user
password=pass
changeLogFile=changesets/scottTiger.xml
logLevel=info
```

Comment: O`Connor , that seems really interesting . I have several databases (mysql) and need to setup during application (php) installation. I do it mostly with bash scripts. I wonder if we have use `Apache Ivy` for that purposes

Comment: @sakhunzai Liquibase is a java program and ivy is used to download and cache java program dependencies. Just update the ivy.xml file to download the mysql driver jar and change the URL in the liquibase properties file. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

To install Liquibase, you need to follow the below steps

1. Install and extract [Liquibase binaries](http://download.liquibase.org/download/?frm=y)
2. Install [Java JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html)
3. Install your database's JDBC driver
4. Make Liquibase accessible across OS by setting Path variable

The detailed steps are [here](https://medium.com/@xameeramir/how-to-install-automated-database-deployment-tool-liquibase-3c21f442698f)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Use the following command: `wget https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/download/v3.8.1/liquibase-3.8.1.tar.gz`

For you to get the correct URL, go to the liquibase [download page](https://download.liquibase.org/download/?frm=y) and use the browser inspect function in the URL. There you will get the correct link to use with `wget`.